# BeautifulSoupでのリンクの選出

Tags: python, python3, beautifulsoup

現在、BeautifulSoupｗ用いてスクライブを行っています。
あるサイトではHTMLでのリンクとPDFでのリンクが同ページにあるのですが、PDFのリンクだけを取得したいです。
下記のコードだとPDF,HTMLのリンクが混じったものがprintで出てきてしまいます。
htmlのリンクを除外する方法をお教示お願いできればと思い質問させていただきました。

```
for a_tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    link_pdf = (urljoin(cur_url, a_tag.get('href')))
    #行の始めがjavaを除外
    if link_pdf.startswith('javascript'):
        continue
    #行の終わりがpdf、/を除外
    if link_pdf.endswith('pdf'):
        continue
    if link_pdf.endswith('/'):
        continue
    #行内にpdfがあるか
    #if link_pdf.find('pdf'):
        #continue
    print(link_pdf)
```

Comment: link_pdfで除外したいけど混じってしまうHTMLのリンクとはどういうものですか？

Comment: https://www.pmda.go.jp/PmdaSearch/kikiDetail/GeneralList/22700BZX00036000_A_01
https://www.pmda.go.jp/PmdaSearch/kikiDetail/ResultDataSetPDF/650051_22700BZX00036000_A_01_01
上がHTMLのリンクで下がPDFのリンクです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PDFのリンクだけを取得したいです。

PDFのURLが必ず`"/ResultDataSetPDF/"`を含むのであれば、
以下のように含まないものを除外すれば良いと思います。
(URLの拡張子も確認するように修正しました。)

```
for a_tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    link = (urljoin(cur_url, a_tag.get('href')))

    # pdfの拡張を持たず、かつ、linkにPDFディレクトリの指定がなければ除外
    if (not link.lower().endswith(".pdf")) and ("/ResultDataSetPDF/" not in link):
        continue

    print(link)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。正常に動作し、pdfのみを出力することができました。また　"/ResultDataSetPDF/"　に加え、例えば末字がpdfの物も抽出するとなった場合、条件追加などはできますでしょうか？

Comment: @西木野有栖 さん URLの拡張子も確認するように修正しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: @tanalab2さん　ありがとうございます・・!確認致しました。どちらも正常に出力されました。助かりました・・ありがとうございます

Comment: @西木野有栖 さん お疲れ様でした。回答を承認(チェックを付ける?)して、回答をクローズしておいてください。